# Adding spacing to the right and bottom of a widget in SWT

Tags: java, swt

When using the `GridLayout` in SWT, one can use the `verticalIndent` and `horizontalIndent` to add spacing to the top and right of a widget. Is there a way to add spacing to the right and bottom side of a widget? I haven't found any methods to do this. Have I missed something?

Answer (score 1):

`GridData` doesn't support setting spacing to the right. But you can simply set a `horizontalIndent` to the widget right to your widget, which should have the same effect. Also `GridLayout` has a `marginRight`.

I had a look at your [code](http://pastebin.com/01RxKeEr) (which you referenced in another question), and shivered remembering my experiences with GridLayout. My recommendation is not to use GridLayout. Have a look at [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/). Start the Web Start demo on the page, read the cheat sheet.

If you compare the code for a complex layout done with GridLayout with the code when using MigLayout, you'll never want to use GridLayout again.

Comment: HI the.duckman. I don't have a control to the right. It is the rightmost control in the row. I need to make a dialog similar to this one. http://imgur.com/p935o You can make out the spacing to the left of the check-box and to the right of the button. It's just one dialog I need but it's been a nightmare. MigLayout sounds great. I had a quick look through it. Since I need only one dialog, i thought I could accomplish this using the GridLayout. My first attempt was using absolute positioning but people don't seem to recommend it.

Comment: If you insist on GridLayout, the way to go for such "complicated" use cases are nested Composites. With that you can achieve what you aim for. But that's hell...

Comment: You might want to consider switching to the much more customizable [`FormLayout`](http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/layout/FormLayout.html).

Comment: how do you do that in FormLayout? any thought there? FormLayout let you set the numertator, denominator and offset, but the problem here is, once your layout get wider, your space would get wider too, thats not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I use an empty `Label` next to my widget where I want a right side indent. 
You just have to increment the columns of your `GridLayout` by one and increment the other widgets horizontal span by one where you don't have this "right side space" `Label`:

```
Label spaceLbl = new Label(parent, SWT.NONE);
GridData gd = new GridData();
gd.horizontalIndent = 5;
spaceLbl.setLayoutData(gd);
```